# How to use Primary Key as a foreignkey in Django

Tags: django, django-models

My Model is

```
class RoomInfo(models.Model):
    hall = models.ForeignKey(Hallinfo, unique=True)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)

class HallInfo(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(RoomInfo, unique=True)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
```

I want to use each others model key as ForeignKey but getting error as "Hallinfo is not defined" and if I define HallInfo above RoomInfo it gives error RoomInfo is not define

Comment: Do you mean they should be a `ManyToMany`?..

Comment: This structure makes no sense. Why do you want them both to have FKs to the other?

Answer (score 2):

If you're defining a foreign key on both sides of the relationship you either need a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) or possibly a [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield).

So just delete both foreign keys and define a many to many or one to one on one side of the relationship..

```
class RoomInfo(models.Model):
    hall = models.OneToOneField(Hallinfo)
```

Comment: beat me by 5 seconds :( +1

Comment: @e4c5 - I would have done it earlier but couldn't decide if m2m or o2o was what the op was trying to do :) (Assuming that since they must be unique then its one to one)

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can use string references [[1]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

```
class RoomInfo(models.Model):
    hall = models.ForeignKey("Hallinfo", unique=True)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)

class HallInfo(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey("RoomInfo", unique=True)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
```

But also you need to add `null=True` at least in one ForeignKey field, or you won't be able to save first instance of a model without required reference value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using another way to declare FK.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Personnaly I always use this notation:

```
manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
    'app_name.ModelName',
    ....
)
```

In your case:

```
> class RoomInfo(models.Model):
>     hall = models.ForeignKey('appname.Hallinfo', unique=True)
>     mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
> 
> class HallInfo(models.Model):
>     room = models.ForeignKey('appname.RoomInfo', unique=True)
>     mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
```